TensorRT migrate from 8 to 10
I am migrating code from TensorRT 8.4 to TensorRT 10.
A function called 'getBindingIndex' has been deprecated. The Migration guide here:
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/migration-guide/index.html
States to replace with safe::name-based methods. But i cannot figure out what that means.
How can i update these two functions to TensorRT 10 compatibility?
//!
//! \brief Returns the size of the host and device buffers that correspond to tensorName.
//!        Returns kINVALID_SIZE_VALUE if no such tensor can be found.
//!
size_t size(const std::string& tensorName) const
{
    int index = mEngine->getBindingIndex(tensorName.c_str());
    if (index == -1)
        return kINVALID_SIZE_VALUE;
    return mManagedBuffers[index]->hostBuffer.nbBytes();
}



 void* getBuffer(const bool isHost, const std::string& tensorName) const
 {
      
     int index = mEngine->getBindingIndex(tensorName.c_str());
     if (index == -1)
         return nullptr;
     return (isHost ? mManagedBuffers[index]->hostBuffer.data() : mManagedBuffers[index]->deviceBuffer.data());
 }

